# python multiprocessing with shared variables and asynchronous?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am new to multiprocessing in python. i encounter a algorithm's program. i have stucked in it for almost one week. I will appreciate the help greatly.
I will show the algorithm.
Global variables *X*,*k* among multi processes.

1. Read variable X from global memory
2. Loop  while k < 100 (the k is shared memory counter)

   ```
     a). k=k+1, globaly
     b). Read y from the global memory with locks
     c). compute _g=G(k,y,x)
     d). USING _g to update the y and X,globally, with locks
   ```

   END

Answer (score 2):

You can not share variables or any other builtin type across processes. For sharing the data across processes, [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module has two types:

1. [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)
2. [`Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe)

Check: [Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) document.

---

[`Queue` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) says:

> Returns a process shared queue implemented using a pipe and a few locks/semaphores. When a process first puts an item on the queue a feeder thread is started which transfers objects from a buffer into the pipe.

As per [`Pipe` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe):

> Returns a pair (conn1, conn2) of Connection objects representing the ends of a pipe.
>
> If duplex is True (the default) then the pipe is bidirectional. If duplex is False then the pipe is unidirectional: conn1 can only be used for receiving messages and conn2 can only be used for sending messages.

Comment: May be that's because I haven't provided the actual code/example which would work for OP. And, that is because I do not know what OP wants to achieve. I would have appreciated if down-voter could leave a comment addressing the issue, which would help me in improving the answer